# Default values for iterable unpacking

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

I've often been frustrated by the lack of flexibility in Python's iterable unpacking.

Take the following example:

```
a, b = range(2)
```

Works fine. `a` contains `0` and `b` contains `1`, just as expected. Now let's try this:

```
a, b = range(1)
```

Now, we get a `ValueError`:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Not ideal, when the desired result was `0` in `a`, and `None` in `b`.

There are a number of hacks to get around this. The most elegant I've seen is this:

```
a, *b = function_with_variable_number_of_return_values()
b = b[0] if b else None
```

Not pretty, and could be confusing to Python newcomers.

So what's the most Pythonic way to do this? Store the return value in a variable and use an if block? The `*varname` hack? Something else?

Comment: The most pythonic way is not to have the function return a variable number of things. Either return a container, or a consistent number of things, or raise an error (from the function or on unpacking) if it can't meet the requirements of its interface for some reason.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, what about functions that return lists?

Comment: Well that *is* a container, and semantically it's unusual to have specific requirements for the number of things in a list.

Comment: What’s an example of a real-world situation when you’ve needed this? It affects the right solution.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, true, but it might be useful if you were doing something along the lines of `a, b, *rest = function_returning_list()`

Comment: Yes, maybe, but are you? As @Ryan says this requires some concrete context. There isn't a general solution; `b = b[0] if b else None` potentially ignores the third and above elements, quietly ignoring an unexpected occurrence, which is absolutely not Pythonic. And there *should* be an error in that case if you need two things but it only gives one.

Comment: @Ryan, it's mostly a hypothetical question, but here's an example of where it might be useful: You're processing command line arguments, and you want to split out the first few, but provide defaults if they're not there. In that case, `_, arg1, arg2, *rest = sys.argv` would sometimes work, but would often raise an error.

Comment: In that case I'd recommend using `argparse`, which will also generate useful help for you, or something like `click`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, going with the list example, you could use something like `b, rest = (b[0], b[1:]) if b else (None, [])`

Comment: @jonrsharpe, again, it's mostly a hypothetical question. That was just an example.

Comment: You *could*, but I really wouldn't. This isn't an answerable question in the general case.

Comment: Like @jonrsharpe said, `argparse` would be better for parsing arguments, and it really does depend on the situation otherwise. You could use `iter()` and `next()` with a default, or a wrapper around that, or coroutines, or a function that fills in up to some number of values with defaults, or…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the best way to do this is to simply have your function return a constant number of values and if your use case is actually more complicated (like argument parsing), use a library for it.

*However*, your question explicitly asked for a Pythonic way of handling functions that return a variable number of arguments and I believe it can be cleanly accomplished with [decorators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/). They're not super common and most people tend to use them more than create them so here's a [down-to-earth tutorial on creating decorators](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/03/simple-python-decorator-examples/) to learn more about them.

Below is a decorated function that does what you're looking for. The function returns an iterator with a variable number of arguments and it is padded up to a certain length to better accommodate iterator unpacking.

```
def variable_return(max_values, default=None):
    # This decorator is somewhat more complicated because the decorator
    # itself needs to take arguments.
    def decorator(f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            actual_values = f(*args, **kwargs)
            try:
                # This will fail if `actual_values` is a single value.
                # Such as a single integer or just `None`.
                actual_values = list(actual_values)
            except:
                actual_values = [actual_values]
            extra = [default] * (max_values - len(actual_values))
            actual_values.extend(extra)
            return actual_values
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@variable_return(max_values=3)
# This would be a function that actually does something.
# It should not return more values than `max_values`.
def ret_n(n):
    return list(range(n))

a, b, c = ret_n(1)
print(a, b, c)
a, b, c = ret_n(2)
print(a, b, c)
a, b, c = ret_n(3)
print(a, b, c)
```

Which outputs what you're looking for:

```
0 None None
0 1 None
0 1 2
```

The decorator basically takes the decorated function and returns its output along with enough extra values to fill in `max_values`. The caller can then assume that the function always returns exactly `max_values` number of arguments and can use fancy unpacking like normal.

Comment: This is a nice idea. I'd not thought of using decorators.

Comment: The body of `wrapper` could be replaced with `return islice(chain(f(*args, **kwargs), repeat(default)), max_values)` (requiring `from itertools import islice, chain, repeat`)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative version of the decorator solution by @supersam654, using iterators rather than lists for efficiency:

```
def variable_return(max_values, default=None):
    def decorator(f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            actual_values = f(*args, **kwargs)
            try:
                for count, value in enumerate(actual_values, 1):
                    yield value
            except TypeError:
                count = 1
                yield actual_values
            yield from [default] * (max_values - count)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

It's used in the same way:

```
@variable_return(3)
def ret_n(n):
    return tuple(range(n))

a, b, c = ret_n(2)
```

This could also be used with non-user-defined functions like so:

```
a, b, c = variable_return(3)(range)(2)
```

Comment: The body of `wrapper` could be replaced with `return islice(chain(f(*args, **kwargs), repeat(default)), max_values)` (requiring `from itertools import islice, chain, repeat`)

Answer (score 0):

Shortest known to me version (thanks to @KellyBundy in comments below):

```
a, b, c, d, e, *_ = *my_list_or_iterable, *[None]*5
```

Obviously it's possible to use other default value than `None` if necessary.

Also there is one nice feature in Python 3.10 which comes handy here when we know upfront possible numbers of arguments - like when unpacking `sys.argv`

Previous method:

```
import sys.argv

_, x, y, z, *_ = *sys.argv, *[None]*3
```

New method:

```
import sys


match sys.argv[1:]: #slice needed to drop first value of sys.argv
    case [x]:
        print(f'x={x}')
    case [x,y]:
        print(f'x={x}, y={y}')
    case [x,y,z]:
        print(f'x={x}, y={y}, z={z}')
    case _:
        print('No arguments')
```

Comment: @KellyBundy - fair notice. Fixed example.

Comment: Btw, my usual suggestion is [a bit shorter](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P7cyPrMktSgxKSdVwVahKDEvPVXDWJOLK1FHIUlHIVlHIUVHASSjUVJakJOqgaRcU0FbQcMvPy9VR1PLVDPayjSWq6AoM69EA0UrulE6ClrxQOO0kAwCCkWDzInVMsVqwv//AA).

Comment: Nice! I've forgot about this notation.

Comment: What you have now as "Previous method" doesn't work, as you removed your slicing.

Comment: (facepalm) - fixed and tested