# Automatically extend a Python list to N elements if it's too short?

Tags: python, list

What is the best way in Python to automatically extend a list to `N` elements, if the list has fewer than `N` elements?

That is, let's have I have this string: `s = "hello there"`.  If I do this:

```
x, y, z = s.split()
```

I will get an error, because `s.split()` returns a list of two elements, but I'm assigning it to 3 variables.  What I want is for `z` to be assigned `None`.

I know I can do this the hard way:

```
l = s.split()
while len(l) < 3:
    l.append(None)
x, y, z = l
```

But there has to be something more elegant than this.

Comment: Your code doesn't have anything  wrong IMHO, is quite readable.

Comment: I was hoping for a one-liner that avoids the while-loop.

Comment: You can try x, y, *z= s.split() Which in the case of more than 3 elements on the right side makes a list inside z

Comment: Also: [Returning None or a tuple and unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1274875/7851470)

Comment: Related: [Safe unpack empty tuple array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54469369/7851470)

Comment: For extending a list to N elements see: [Some built-in to pad a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3438756/7851470)

Answer (score 27):

If you want a one-liner, do:

```
s = "hello there"
x, y, z, *_ = s.split() + [None, None, None]

print(x, y, z)
```

**Output**

```
hello there None
```

Note that a one-liner is not necessarily more readable nor more elegant. A variation, thanks to @Grismar is:

```
x, y, z, *_ = s.split() + [None] * 3
```

Comment: Depending on the number of `None`s, I'd prefer `x, y, z, *_ = s.split() + [None] * 3` - it has the number right in there, which would be more readable for a larger number, makes it easier to parameterise and is shorter to boot.

Comment: If you want to get rid of `*_`, you can write it `x, y, z = (s.split() + [None]*3)[:3]`

Comment: itertools.chain(s.split(), itertools.repeat(None))

Comment: @RiaD: Good idea, but with `x, y, z = chain(s.split(), repeat(None)` you'll get a `ValueError: too many values to unpack`, and with `x, y, z, *_ = chain(s.split(), repeat(None)` you'll get an attempt to build an infinite list in `_` which will block until it has eaten all available memory.

Comment: ah, you are right, so have to add slice and it's becoming too long

Answer (score 16):

`extend` adds an iterable to the end of a list, so you can do:

```py
l.extend(None for _ in range(3 - len(l))
```

or

```py
l.extend([None]*(3-len(l)))
```

which is a bit more elegant but slightly slower because it needs to construct the list of Nones first.

Answer (score 7):

This sort of application is exactly what the `padnone` recipe in `itertools` is for (https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
x, y, z = itertools.islice(itertools.chain(s.split(), itertools.repeat(None)), 3)
```

The above also incorporates `take` to get just 3 elements.

Comment: Be careful not to run the variant to this without islice: `x, y, z, *_ = itertools.chain(s.split(), itertools.repeat(None))` as it will happily try and create a infinite iterable in `_`. Providing a value for amount of repetitions works though `x, y, z, *_ = itertools.chain(s.split(), itertools.repeat(None, 10))`

Answer (score 6):

Here's a mildly amusing solution using [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest): the behaviour is to use `None` to fill in the missing elements in the shorter sequence.

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

(x, _), (y, _), (z, _) = zip_longest(s.split(), range(3))
```

Like your original code, this will throw an error if `s.split()` has more than three parts. If you prefer to silently discard the extra parts, destructure to `(x, _), (y, _), (z, _), *_` instead.

Comment: You could do: x,y, z = (k for k, _ in zip_longest(s.split(), range(3)))

Comment: Yes, I wrote it that way first but then decided this way was slightly cleaner. A matter of opinion, of course.

Answer (score 3):

An **alternative** approach would be to assign z to a blank string using partition.

```
s = "hello there" 
x, z, y = s.partition(' ')
```

This approach cuts to the chase. In doing so, it leaves z assigned to a blank instead of None.

Comment: It does completely different thing: instead of splitting any amount of substrings it splits only on first separator occurence and returns left part, separator, and the right part

Answer (score 3):

A flexible decorator-based solution inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59141795/8164958) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44627436/8164958) answer:

```py
from itertools import islice, chain, repeat

def variable_return(max_values, default=None):
    def decorator(f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return islice(chain(f(*args, **kwargs), repeat(default)), max_values)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Or a pointlessly condensed version:

```py
variable_return = lambda m, d=None: lambda f: lambda *a, **k: islice(chain(f(*a, **k), repeat(d)), m)
```

It can be used like this:

```py
@variable_return(3)
def split(s):
    return s.split()

x, y, z = split(s) # ('hello', 'there', None)
```

or like this:

```py
x, y, z = variable_return(3)(s.split)() # ('hello', 'there', None)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could add the single-item list `[None]` the required number of times (edit: similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59131202/5801744) but without using `extend`):

```
l += [None]*(3-len(l))
```